# While creating loop carousel with elementor pro, "create a template" button does not allow me to create a template

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am creating my first wordpress website. I have the elementor pro plugin installed on my website. One of the pro elements that comes with this is the "Loop Carousel".

[image]

Everything seems to be working when I add it to my page, but then I click the "Create a template" button then the bar on the left still shows "Edit Loop Carousel", but the actual page reflects a blank page with only a footer and header as shown below:

[image]

According to this youtube video this is the screen that it should be showing me after I select "Create a Template":

[image]

Does anybody know why I am unable edit the loop carousel?